# How end the loop if the total number exceed the certain number?

Tags: python, loops

I wanted to end the loop when the total of rabbits is over 500 but it doesn't seem to work right now, is there any other way to end the loop if it overs a certain number?

```
    for i in range(20):
        timePasses()
        displayEndOfTheMonthStatus()
        totalRabbits
        if totalRabbits == 500:
            break

print("out of cages")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: We need more info on other methods you are using in this code snippet. What is `timePasses()`, `displayEndOfTheMonthStatus()`? and also, why do you add `totalRabbits`? It seems that it's not a method, it won't do anything.

Comment: This code just gives an IndentationError on the first line.  Make a [mcve] and format the code properly.

Comment: Please add complete code so that your issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a `while` loop (e.g.

```py
while(totalRabbits < 501):
    do things
```

Alternatively, check your condition statement. You are breaking on if `totalRabbits` is exactly equal to 500? Is this condition ever met? Is it possible for `totalRabbits` to skip from say 499 to 501 directly?